# Weka Save Model Menu is Always Disabled

Tags: weka

I am trying out Weka and I've found that, so far, every option I've tried (all types of trees) for classification did not allow me to save the model because that option was grayed out and disabled.  How do I save a model?

[image]

Comment: Curious. I can't replicate this. It is true that you probably can't save the model to the Weka 3.8 folder (you'll get an access denied error and will need to choose another folder), but I'm still showing that the save option isn't grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

In WEKA explorer make sure "Output Model" is enabled from "More options". This setting should change to "Store Output Model" to make sense to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the results on my ArchLinux and mac OSx on Weka 3.8 and I did not have the problem you mentioned. Are you on Windows? If so, I recommend reinstalling the latest stable version.

Comment: Yes, on Windows